# Xamarin Forms File System Access (Cross Platform)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm working on a cross platform application that needs full access to the file system. I'll eventually be targeting both **Windows** and **Mac**.

Ultimately, I need to be able to read/write audio file properties (author, genre, etc) for files located anywhere on the system.

I've set the UWP app to have **Broad File System Access** in the manifest, but this doesn't seem to be enough: access is still denied.

- Using *FilePicker* is fine for first time access, but the
  application will need read/write access to files without the user
  picking them all the time
- The *Code Sharing Strategy* is **.NET Standard** instead of *Shared
  Project*
- I'm wanting to use [TagLib](https://github.com/timheuer/taglib-sharp-portable) to read/write the file properties (alternatives are welcome)
- My test environment is Windows 10 (so I'm running the UWP app)
- Test files are currently located on the desktop

I remember seeing somewhere that once you open a file with *FilePicker* you can save the reference/filepath in some app settings so that access will be granted automatically when the app wants to access it without the user. I want to try this, but I can't remember where I read it.

What would be the best approach and/or next steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I remember seeing somewhere that once you open a file with FilePicker you can save the reference/filepath in some app settings so that access will be granted automatically when the app wants to access it without the user.

[`StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist) property may be what you want. It could be used to get an object that represents a list that an app maintains so that the app can store files and/or locations (like folders) and easily access these items in the future. For usage details please refer to the following code:

```
static public string FolderAccessToken { get; set; }
private async void Pick_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new FolderPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");        
    var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (folder == null)
    {
        FolderAccessToken = "";
        return;
    }

    FolderAccessToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
}

private async void Get_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(FolderAccessToken);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used that (FutureAccessList) in combination with the file streams from using [StorageFile].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite). All seems to be working as required. The last hurdle is increasing the maximum list count of FutureAccessList from 1,000. I'm hoping I can just simply create a new "StorageApplicationPermissions" class and extend it there. Let's see!

Comment: Did this work on a Mac as well as Android and iOS devices?